# How To show Password Wrong error to Users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i have a problem in showing error for users this is my Auth Login Controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
  
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */
  
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
  
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
  
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
 
    public function login(Request $request)
    {   
        $input = $request->all();
     
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:8',
        ]);
     
        if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password'])))
        {
            if (auth()->user()->type == 'admin') {
                return redirect()->route('admin.home');
            }else if (auth()->user()->type == 'manager') {
                return redirect()->route('manager.home');
            }else{
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('login')
                ->with('error','Email-Address And Password Are Wrong.');
        }

        $messages = [
            'email.required' => 'Email is required',
            'email.email' => 'Invalid email format',
            'password.required' => 'Password is required',
            'password.min' => 'Password must be at least 8 characters',
        ];
          
    }
}
```

This is the LoginController from the default app in laravel i don't know why the messages of password wrong can't be showed in screen when i type wrong pass

i want to show users error if they use wrong password and this is the github link :
https://github.com/ElGrandeAchraf/skipshiftProjectCode.git

And Thank you For your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I was looking at the right Blade file, but in your `resources/views/login.blade.php` file I haven't seen anywhere that you would actually have the code to show errors. The controller doesn't do that for you automatically.

I you are returning `with('error')` then you should show it in Blade, something like:

```
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="error">{{ session('error') }}</div>
@endif
```